# Not able to save settings in phpList admin panel

Tags: phplist

I am integrating phpList into my website. I initialized database. 
I was able to integrate my website with phpList.

In admin panel whenever i try to do anything like delete member from subscriber list or change any setting for subscriber page. I am getting this error "**The requested URL /index.php was not found on this server**."

I know that this is the problem of path.

When user receives email it says to confirm click on this.

http://admin.ridesharebuddy.com/lists/?p=preferences&uid=TOKEN

When user clicks on this, it displays error page not found.

Because path should be something like this.

http://admin.ridesharebuddy.com/rideshare/lists/?p=preferences&uid=TOKEN

How can i change this path ?

Comment: did u check the path of website in config.php of phplist

Comment: i don't see any path in config.php of phplist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So from what I see, you have 2 issues:

Firstly:

- index.php is not being found.
  This is generally because of a) an upload error, or b) missing directory traversals within the script (../../ etc..)
  What we need to know is why index.php is not found, and why it is being called when you try to make a change

Secondly:

- The link generated when the email is sent, is incorrect. This will just be a case of finding where the link is generated, and modifying it to generate a correct code.

If you could update the post with source for the files, then I may be able to help you further.

If you feel you can't do the above, then I suggest using a different, more mature (and better coded), mailing script for your site.